# Share Apple Developer Program

Tags: apple-developer-account

I have developed an app with my Apple Developer Program for some third party company.(Let's call it account A)
after awhile the company decide to create a new app with other developer team (so they have account B), and they want only the old app's bundle identifier for the new app (they didn't want source code).

how can I share my Apple Developer Program to other team so they have access to it for developing and distributing?

Is this the right way?

Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you login to appstoreconnect.apple.com with the Apple ID associated with your Apple Developer Program, you can add team members in the **Users and Access** section. The roles, like Admin, Developer and more, that you assign to each team member determines what they actually can do with your Apple Developer Program.

Comment: According to your statement can they (another developer team) create a new Xcode project with my bundle identifier?

Comment: @behrad Yes, if you add the developer as team member with developer role, and the developer in question adds his team member account in Xcode settings, he can use any bundle identifier that's registered within the Developer Program.